# Custom Directive in nuxt js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

is there a way how to write a custom directive in nuxt js, which will work for ssr and also for frontend (or even for ssr only)?

I tried it like in following documentation: 
https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-render#bundleRenderer

so I added this code:

```
  module.exports = {
      render: {
        bundleRenderer: {
          directives: {
            custom1: function (el, dir) {
              // something ...
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

to nuxt.config.js

then I use it in template as:

```
<component v-custom1></component>
```

but it doesn't work, it just throw the frontend error

[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: custom1

And it doesn't seem to be working even on server side.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: thanks @Sphinx, but that's in general the same code as I pasted and it doesn't work for me, don't you have some working example please?

Comment: I met the same problem as yours now (Nuxt.js 1.4.0). I just tried `bundleRenderer.shouldPreload` it works fine, but `bundleRenderer.directives` didn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tested in nuxt-edge ( its nuxt 2.0 that will be out in this or next month, but its pretty stable as it is).

nuxt.config.js

```
  render: {
    bundleRenderer: {
      directives: {
        cww: function (vnode, dir) {
          const style = vnode.data.style || (vnode.data.style = {})
          style.backgroundColor = '#ff0016'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

page.vue

```
<div v-cww>X</div>
```

Resulting html from server:

```
<div style="background-color:#ff0016;">X</div>
```

Comment: How would you set innerText of the element?

Comment: @TimarIvoBatis Try this one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59401783/how-to-set-innertext-with-directive-in-ssr-vue-nuxt

Comment: Thanks haha that was my question and also my answer :D

Comment: PS: I've also did a small write up on custom SSR directives: https://blog.lichter.io/posts/universal-ssr-vue-component-guide/#directives

Answer (score 28):

If you want use custom directives in Nuxt you can do the following:

- Create a file inside plugins folder, for example, directives.js
- In nuxt.config.js add something like `plugins: ['~/plugins/directives.js']`

In your new file add your custom directive like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.directive('focus', {
  inserted: (el) => {
    el.focus()
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks for a hint, but this works only on frontend, it doesn't have any effect on server side rendered html.

Comment: Worked by using `bind` and `unbind` in this syntax.

Answer (score 13):

## How To Create A Directive

---

You can make directives run on the client by adding the `.client.js` extension to your directives file. This works for `SSR` and `static` rendering.

```js
// plugins/directive.client.js

import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.directive('log-inner-text', {
  inserted: el => {
    console.log(el.innerText)
  }
})
```

---

### How To Insert Directives

In your `nuxt.config.js` file add it as a plugin like this.

```js
plugins: [
  '~/plugins/directive.client.js'
]
```

Don't forget to save your directive in the plugins folder.

---

### How To Use A Directive

```html
<div v-log-inner-text>Hello</div>
```

Console logs

```
> "Hello"
```

I have written a medium article that goes a lot more in-depth on how this works. It shows you how to make a directive that makes an element animate into view on scroll: **[Nuxt - Creating Custom Directives For Static & SSR Sites](https://medium.com/@fletcherrippon/nuxt-creating-custom-directives-for-static-srr-sites-bf287f0cb6bb)**

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else coming here, the accepted answer allows you to run an SSR-only directive. This is helpful but a little unintuitive if you want to have a directive run everywhere.

If you **only** use nuxt.config.js to implement a directive via `render`, it will not be supported on the client-side without also adding a directive plugin and adding it to the config (see the How to Create a Directive Answer).

To test this out, try this experiment:

- Follow the instructions to create directive using plugins (make one called loading)

```
Vue.directive('loading', function (el, binding) {
  console.log('running loading directive client side')
})
```

- Add this to your nuxt.config:

```
  render: {
    bundleRenderer: {
      directives: {
        loading (element, binding) {
          console.log('running loading directive server side')
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Use the directive on a Vue page file like:

```
<div v-loading="true">Test</div>
```

On page load, you will see both the client-side and SSR directives run. And if you remove the client-side directive, you will see errors thrown like the OP had: `[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: loading`.

Tested on nuxt 2.12.2.