# How to set InnerText with directive in SSR Vue/Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, vue-ssr

I want to port my vue directive to also render server side.

client side:

```
mydirective(el,binding,vnode){
    el.innerText = vnode.context.$data.points
}
```

What i have working so far in nuxt.config.js:

```
render: {
    bundleRenderer: {
      directives: {
        mydirective(node, binding){
             var points = node.context.$data.points //works 
             node.data.style = [{backgroundColor: 'green'}] //works
             node.data.innerText = points  //NOT working
             node.data.textContent = points  //NOT working
        }
```

I cant find the element reference.

i used the following function to search through the node object:

```
  Object.keys(node).forEach(key=>{
    console.log(key)
    console.log( node[key])
    console.log('============================%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%================================')
  })
enter code here
```

Comment: You have a  minor typo. Change innterText to innerText and see if it works for you.

Comment: unfortunately the typo was only in the question, in my code ithere was none.

Comment: All good! console.log(node.data) after node.data.style = [{backgroundColor: 'green'}] and see if there's an innerText property you can set.

Comment: thats the problem. not even the style property is there. The only reason i know about it is because of this example  that performs this check: `node.data.style || (node.data.style = {}` https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/platforms/web/server/directives/show.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:

```
mydirective(node, binding){
     var points = node.context.$data.points
     node.data.domProps = {
          innerHTML: points
        }
}
```

documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Virtual-DOM

Comment: unfortunately this will cause hydtration issues

Comment: Works fine, does not seem to cause any issues for me